# php- getting wrong values while looping

Tags: php, wordpress

I am making an opportunity form where i have provided update and delete functionality in wordpress. my question is what is wrong with this for loop .. I am getting wrong values for i. 
it is unable to print a "$opportunity_exp_date[$i]" if i delete any single opportunity. It might tough to understand for you guys but it is my problem.
Here is my code.

```
for($i=count($contact_opportunity);$i>=0;$i--){  //for listing of Won opportunities
    if($contact_opportunity[$i]!='0' && !empty($contact_opportunity[$i])){ ?>
    <?php if($opportunity_status[$i]=='Won'){?> 
        <div class="won-opp"><h3>Won</h3></div>              
        <?php echo "<div class='oname'>"."New Opportunity '".$contact_opportunity[$i]."' added"."</div>"; ?>
        <a href="<?php echo admin_url( "admin.php?page=contact_profile&post=$pid&opnm=$contact_opportunity[$i]&opamt=$opportunity_amount[$i]&opedt=$opportunity_exp_date[$i]&opsts=$opportunity_status[$i]&opnt=$opportunity_note[$i]" )?>"><span class="opp-edit" title="edit"></span></a> 
        <span class="btn_remove_opp" title="delete opportunity"></span>             
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $contact_opportunity[$i]?>" class="del_op_nm">
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $opportunity_status[$i]?>" class="del_op_sts">
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $opportunity_exp_date[$i]?>" class="del_op_exp">
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $opportunity_amount[$i]?>" class="del_op_amt">
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $opportunity_note[$i]?>" class="del_op_nt">
        <div id="opp-list">
        <?php                       
            echo "<span class='sts'>".$opportunity_status[$i]."</span>"." Expected close on ".$opportunity_exp_date[$i]."<br>";
            echo $opportunity_amount[$i]." "."<div class='footer-op-nt'>".$opportunity_note[$i]."</div>"."<br>";
        ?>                                                              
        </div>
        <br>
    <?php }
    }
}
```

Comment: Without some data and output its impossible to figure out. You may want to switch to `foreach($contact_opportunity as $i->$value)` if your deleteing values and breaking the series

Comment: You might be better off sorting the opportunities, and then using a foreach loop instead of a for loop.

Comment: sorting opportunities will require sorting all the other data too, as the keys will no longer match (e.g. $opportunity_note, $opportunity_exp_date)

Comment: Although not pointed out by @Adder their codes does state `count($contact_opportunity)` is not the last element, as numerical indexes should start from 0, so `count($contact_opportunity)-1` is the loop starting point

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are off by one; don't use count() in loops it is slower xD

```
$count= count($contact_opportunity);
for($i=$count-1;$i>=0;--$i){ //for listing of Won opportunities
```